# Why is my HP TouchSmart tx2 1025dx shutting down?

Tags: windows-vista

I'm having an issue with my HP tx2 1025dx laptop.  Sometimes it will spontaneously shut itself off. First, the screen will go out. Next, the computer itself will shut down. This usually occurs when I am doing something that requires a lot of resources, but lately can happen when I am doing something as simple as using an Office app.

I think it may be heat related, if I try to boot the laptop after it shuts itself down, it will shut itself down again before startup is complete.  If I let it cool down for a while and then come back to it, the computer will boot properly.  These shutdowns are always accompanied by high temperatures on the bottom right side, as well as the right side of the keyboard.  I am using a laptop cooler with two fans, and it is not making a bit of difference.

This is the second TouchSmart we have owned, the first one had the same issues, we sent it in to HP after it finally refused to reboot.  They “fixed” it, and it worked fine for about a month before doing the exact same thing.  Unfortunately we had bought the second one before the issues began with the original, if I had known this would be a problem, I would not have purchased another TouchSmart.

This particular laptop we have had for more than a year and it didn’t start these issues until a couple of months ago.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your laptop is overheating, which is why leaving it off for a while will allow it to work again.  [HPs Tips for Care](https://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01507270&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=emea_africa&product=3860702&lang=en) suggests you clean the vents with compressed air, which is also what I would recommend.

I have never used a laptop cooler, but I had a similar problem with my laptop and just purchased a smallish fan, about seven inches in diameter and stuck a book underneath it.  This got cool air flowing over the top and bottom and allowed me to play video games for hours longer than it used to.

Comment: I have cleaned all of the vents, but am still having the same heat issue within 20-30 minutes of booting the computer.